# Run ng build and omit templates

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is there a switch or configuration option to run `ng build` and have it not inline the `templateUrl` from the angular components? In my app those urls are hosted by a web server and can be dynamically generated based on the locale of the user (*in short the resource files are maintained server side in a DB and can change at runtime*).

I checked the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build) and searched in the [github repo](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues) without any luck.

Error that `ng build` is throwing for each component.

```
ERROR in ./app/some.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './url-to-template' in 'd:\AppFolder\url-to-template'
 @ [tree / stack]
```

Comment: It doesn't have any undocumented switches. If you're doing something unusual like that, you will likely have to `ng eject` and take more control yourself.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Thank you for your response. I added a [feature request in the Github repo](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7299).